# DFS discovery and finish times

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search

Suppose that we perform DFS on this graph by obeying the following rules:

• Start from vertex 1.

• At every vertex, process its out-neighbors in ascending order of id.

• Whenever we need to restart, do it from the white vertex with the smallest
id

Show the resulting DFS forest. Furthermore, for every vertex, indicate its discovery time and finish time. also #/ = discovered and #/# = finished

[image]

dfs tree as follows:

```
               6
               |
1--2--7--3--4--5--8
```

the question ask me to show the resulting forest, yet I'm only producing one tree, what have i done wrong?

Comment: Forest refers to a group of 1+ trees. Unless I am missing something, a forest of a single tree is also valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed nothing. A forest is a set of graphs and thus even allowed to contain 0 graphs. So the graph-forst in your result is absolutely valid. Some lecturers tend to use their own definition though, so I'd advise to double check that with your script. As for the DFS-traversal it's perfectly valid and pretty simple to show that there exists a path from 1 to **any** node in the tree

Comment: ive realised ive actually made a mistake going to node 2 first rather then 3. but yes your right

Comment: @101ldaniels you didn't. This rules: *At every vertex, process its out-neighbors in ascending order of id* demands you traverse 2 before 3

Comment: wait then in that case ive processed node 8 before 6

Comment: @101ldaniels yeah, didn't notice that one

Answer (score 0):

The discovery time tracks the number of steps in the algorithm before a vertex is first encountered.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).